# Unitary element of the group algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $G$ be a torsion free group. Are unitary elements of $\mathbb CG$ studied? By unitary element I mean an element $\alpha$ in $\mathbb CG$, such that $\alpha^*\alpha=1$? Do the triviality of unitary elements imply the unit conjecture to be true, i.e.$\alpha\beta=1$, $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb CG$ iff $\alpha=\lambda g$ for a $g\in G$.

Comment: You may want to replace $\mathbb{C}$ by another, much smaller ring here. The unit group conjectures usually deal with the units of $\mathbb{Z}G$ or $\mathbb{Q}G$ for example. The complex group algebra simply has way to many units, even unitary ones (as one can easily see by the Wedderburn decomposition). For $\mathbb{Z}G$ on the other extreme, it is easy to see that $x^\ast x =1$ implies $x=\pm g$ for some $g\in G$.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Could you please give an example of non-trivial units (i.e. $\neq\lambda g$) in the complex group algebra of a torsion free group?

Comment: @JohannesHahn The unit conjecture (Kaplansky 1969) is a conjecture with coefficients in an arbitrary field: for $K$ field and $G$ torsion-free group every unit of $KG$ is proportional to a group element.

Comment: In addition, it is true over any field of characteristic zero iff it's true over any number field, by standard arguments.

Comment: @YCor So, there is no unitary element in $\mathbb CG$, because by Johannes's comment, there is no ones in $\mathbb ZG$?

Comment: ?? I didn't say anything about unitary elements, and I don't know what you mean by "there is no unitary element in $CG$" since there are unitary elements. And also I said that Johaness's statement that there are way too many units in $CG$ is probably based on a misunderstanding, since it is in contradiction with Kaplansky's unit conjecture.

Comment: @YCor Sorry, I mean there is no non-trivial unitary elements in $\mathbb CG$ because by Johannes's comment, there is no ones in ZG?

Comment: Why do you still refer to Johannes' comment, as it's probably based on a misreading of the question? (He speaks of Wedderburn decomposition, so probably has finite groups in mind, while you asked about torsion-free groups.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84739/discussion-between-meisam-soleimani-malekan-and-ycor).

Comment: I'm sorry. It was (again I'm ashamed to say) a case of not reading the post as carefully as I should have. Disregard what I said.

Comment: What you are calling unitary would normally be called an isometry.  Unitary usually asks that $\alpha$ and $\alpha^*$ are inverses.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg it is the case in the complex group algebra.

Comment: Is it obvious the group algebra of an infinite group has no noninvertible isometries?

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I think it is proved by Kaplansky that the complex group algebra of all groups (not only infinite ones)  is directly finite, i.e. $ab=1$ iff $ba=1$.

Comment: You are right I think.